# import java.util.Arrays in JDK8

Tags: java, java-8

Has Arrays class been removed in `JDK 8` ?

I just downloaded **jdk-8-ea-bin-b104-windows-i586-22_aug_2013.exe** and tried to compile my program through it, but the import

```
import java.util.Arrays
```

is throwing error, showing `class not found`.

Comment: It's still there. http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Google is your friend

Comment: Don't forget the semicolon.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seemed a typo

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you want this:-

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

instead of

```
import java.util.Arrays
```

> Has Arrays class been removed in JDK 8 ?

No they are not.

Check out [this](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/features) and [this](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

> Add additional utility methods to java.util.Arrays that use the JSR
>   166 Fork/Join parallelism common pool to provide sorting of arrays in
>   parallel.