# Java 8 - Can not import java.util.Arrays

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

After updating to Java 8, I (and a lot of other people) had problems with their eclipse. I resolved the path variable problem. Fine.

So I have old projects in Eclipse. When I have the open, I delete the JRE 7 library and add 8. All the errors go away (from previously error-less code) except an import statement:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

I've seen the other questions on S.O. but they do not answer my problem (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621394/import-java-util-arrays-in-jdk8), which just tells the OP he didn't have a semicolon). Besides it not resolving the source of the import, my code works! So what is it that could have changed?

Comment: I know, that was the first thing I checked. Would've been pretty bizarre if it didn't...

I tried cleaning and it did nothing.

Comment: Looks like your eclipse IDE doesn't support Java 8.

Comment: Actually, that might be it. I'm using Indigo...

Comment: Indigo doesn't support Java 8. Make sure you're using Eclipse Luna or Kepler with a plugin to support Java 8. If your IDE doesn't support Java 8, then it would use Java 1.4 by default.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Put it in answer form and I'll accept it!